# In Rhino Mock, how do I mock a property to it can be “call” more than once?

Tags: .net, mocking, rhino-mocks

This should be easy, so I must be missing something (very likely as this is my first time using Rhino Mock)

I just wish my code to be able to call `helm.CurrentEnterprise` any number of times, but instead I get:

```
System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  Message=Previous method 'IHelm.get_CurrentEnterprise();' requires a return value or an exception to throw.
  Source=Rhino.Mocks
  StackTrace:
       at Rhino.Mocks.Impl.RecordMockState.AssertPreviousMethodIsClose()
       at Rhino.Mocks.Impl.RecordMockState.MethodCall(IInvocation invocation, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
       at Rhino.Mocks.MockRepository.MethodCall(IInvocation invocation, Object proxy, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
       at Rhino.Mocks.Impl.RhinoInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
       at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
       at IHelmProxy44ecadd4f07244fd96c5849febe94a58.get_CurrentEnterprise()
       at KSS.PS3.Testing.UnitTests.ModelOptions.RuleGroupTreeViewTest.AsUsedByRuleGroupModalOptionEditor() in D:\dev\5.0.0\main\Application\Testing\Tests\UnitTests\ModelOptions\RuleGroupTreeView.cs:line 54
  InnerException:
```

This is my code:

```
   MockRepository mocks = new MockRepository();
   IHelm helm = mocks.Stub<IHelm>();
   helm.Stub(x => x.CurrentEnterprise).Return(enterprise).Repeat.Any();         

   var a2 = helm.CurrentEnterprise;
   var a2a = helm.CurrentEnterprise; // <- the exception comes from here
   var a2aa = helm.CurrentEnterprise;
```

Comment: Can you try the same but using `MockRepository.GenerateMock<IHelm>()` instead of `Stub()`?

Comment: @sll, thanks MockRepository.GenerateMock<IHelm>(); worked.  Please can you turn your comment into answer so I can accept it, explaining way GenerateMock work but not Stub would make it a greate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out generate a Mock

```
MockRepository.GenerateMock<IHelm>()
```

Rather than Stub:

```
Stub<IHelm>()
```

[The difference between stubs and mocks](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino%20Mocks%203.5.ashx) (*Rhino Mocks online documentation*)

> A mock is an object that we can set expectations on, and which will
>   verify that the expected actions have indeed occurred. A stub is an
>   object that you use in order to pass to the code under test. You can
>   setup expectations on it, so it would act in certain ways, but those
>   expectations will never be verified. **A stub's properties will
>   automatically behave like normal properties, and you can't set
>   expectations on them**

Answer (score 1):

Gotta say that I don't think a mock is really what you want here.  You are not setting up expectations so that you can call `VerifyAllExpectations` to make certain expected things were called.  I think it's a bit of an unimportant distinction in most cases and your testing here should work with either a mock or a stub.

Just for the sake of posterity and future seekers looking at this question, the reason for the different result when you used the static method `MockRepository.GenerateMock<IHelm>()` instead of the instance `mocks.Stub<IHelm>()` is just that - that you used that different method.  You could have just as easily used `MockRepository.GenerateStub<IHelm>()`.  There answer here is not really at all related to the difference between a mock and a stub.  Your question is not in any way related to setting expectations.